# jquery script not working when loading with .load a remote html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
        $('#id_type').on('change', function () {
            var k = $(this).val();
            if (k == "ci") {
                $(".input_id").attr("placeholder", "<?php echo $lg["ci_ej"]; ?>").placeholder();
            }
            else if (k == "rif") {
                $(".input_id").attr("placeholder", "<?php echo $lg["rif_ej"]; ?>").placeholder();
            }
            else if (k == "pas") {
                $(".input_id").attr("placeholder", "<?php echo $lg["passport_ej"]; ?>").placeholder();
            }
        });
        $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
    });
});
```

it works pretty well when I go directly to the page that use it, but When I call an specific div from the remote html using .load like this:

```
$('.loadiv').load($(this).attr("href") + " .windows-wrapper");
```

the call works well but the first code stop working, i don't understand why. thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Are you saying the change event is not firing?

Comment: yes but just when I call the remote page using .load, if I call the page directly it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute php code into .js files if you are trying from remote js file to do this.

Comment: in fact, it works well because I'm not using it on a .js file, it's on an html.

Answer (score 0):

If you loaded some html and want JQuery to watch for them, the live method is your friend.
Or just rebind JQuery to your document.

I happens because when the page is loaded, JQuery is loaded right after, knowing what the document has.

When you dynamically add new elements, JQuery doesn't know about them because they were loaded after JQuery.

Comment: I think the JQuery docs recommend using .on() and then providing a selector as the second argument. live() is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Yes, the on method, for sure.

Comment: can you give me an example of using .on method on this problem?